# Vue-cli change object value globally

Tags: vue.js

I have this code in file app.vue :

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="component = 'login'">aa</button>
  <component v-bind:is="component"></component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import acceuil from './components/acceuil.vue'
import login from './components/login.vue'
export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    acceuil,
    login
  },
   data(){
    return {
      component: 'acceuil'
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

How can I toggle between acceuil/login in component from a different vue file ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the imported dependency (the object or the name of the component as a string) to `v-bind:is`. You can do this by returning it in a computed function and pass it to a computed property, which you then can use in the template.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button v-on:click="isLogin = true">Show Login</button>
    <component v-bind:is="currentComponent"></component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import acceuil from './components/acceuil.vue';
import login from './components/login.vue';

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      isLogin: false
    };
  },
  computed: {
    currentComponent () {
       return this.isLogin ? login : acceuil;
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

See also the documentation of dynamic components in [the official docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components).

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot `this.` in the computed property. It should work now.